# How to select huge page sizes for DPDK and malloc?

Tags: linux, dpdk, huge-pages

We develop a Linux application that uses DPDK and which must also be heavily optimised for speed.

We must specify huge pages for use by DPDK and also for general dynamic memory allocation. For the latter we use the libhugetlbfs library.

```
sudo mount -t hugetlbfs none /mnt/hugetlbfs
```

We specify the huge pages in the bootcmd line as follows:

```
hugepagesz=1G hugepages=20 hugepages=0 default_hugepagesz=1G
```

We are using Centos 7 and full boot cmdline is:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/centos-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rhgb quiet hugepagesz=1G hugepages=20 default_hugepagesz=1G irqaffinity=0,1 isolcpus=4-23 nosoftlockup mce=ignore_ce idle=poll
```

These values are fairly arbitrary. With these values, I see:

```
$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          47797       45041        2468           9         287        2393
Swap:         23999           0       23999
```

So 2.468GB RAM is free out of 48GB.  So a very large amount of memory is allocated to huge pages and I want to reduce this.

My question is what would be sensible values for them?

I am confused by the interpretation of the parameters. I see:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo
<snip>
HugePages_Total:      43
HugePages_Free:       43
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:    1048576 kB
```

and also:

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/free_hugepages
43
```

Why are 43 pages reported when my parameters only specify 20 pages of 1G?

I would like some guidelines on:

1. huge page size/quantity that I might need for DPDK?
2. huge page size/quantity that I might need for malloc?

I know these are highly application dependant but some guidelines would be helpful. Also how could I detect if the huge pages were insufficent for the application?

Additional info:

```
$ cat /proc/mounts | grep huge
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb cgroup rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb 0 0
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
```

**Update 4 March:**

My boot cmdline is now:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/centos-root ro crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=centos/root rd.lvm.lv=centos/swap rhgb quiet hugepagesz=1G hugepages=20 default_hugepagesz=1G irqaffinity=0,1 isolcpus=4-23 nosoftlockup mce=ignore_ce idle=poll transparent_hugepage=never
```

and transparent hugepages are disabled (I activated a custom tune profile):

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always madvise [never]
```

but I still see 43 hugepages:

```
$ cat /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/free_hugepages
43
```

whereas I have only specified 20 in cmdline. Why is this?

Comment: The `free` command does not show what you think it shows. I suggest you run your system without hugepages, and compare the output of `free` with that.

Comment: Are you also allocating at runtime through the /sys filesystem?

Comment: @datenwolf I deleted the hugepage parameters from cmdline and now 'free' reports 46GB free. So I think it my interpretation that hugepages are deducted from free memory is correct.

Comment: @stark I don't know how DPDK accesses the hugepages (it maybe via /sys). For malloc I just use the default behaviour of hugetlbfs (any use of /sys is transparent to me). So I'm afraid I don't know how to answer your question.

Comment: I reduced the number of 1G pages specified in the boot cmdline. Free memory has increased to 3.487GB (10 pages) from 2.4GB (20 pages).

Comment: @DavidA: The value that `free` reports for *free* memory is the amount of memory that hasn't been assigned any purpose by the kernel. For a long(er) running system this value may drop as low as a few hundred MB (or lower), and most memory being assigned to *buff/cache*. However most memory allocations (i.e. everything that's not backed by huge pages) will come from *buff/cache*. When you do `malloc` or `mmap(…, MAP_ANONYMOUS, …)` without `MAP_HUGETLB` it *will* be cut from the *buff/cache* portion.

Comment: @DavidA: If you want to know, how many hugepages you have available, actually, look at `/sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-…/free_hugepages`.

Comment: Hi @DavidA did you remove the grub cmdline for `2Mb` page reference. Since you have mentioned tin grub the same si reflected as 20 of 1Gb and 20 of 2MB. Please re-run with removing 2MB and update the question.

Comment: @VipinVarghese I have deleted the 2MB parameter and updated the question.

Comment: @datenwolf I have updated the question to show that the value of /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB is 43 (not 20 as I would expect).

Comment: thanks @davidA if you are using UEFi the grub2 location is different, there is no mention of the OS use. So please ensure with `cat  /proc/cmdline` things are proper. I use 1GB huge page in my system with Ubuntu and Centos. I do not face the issue.

Comment: @VipinVarghese I have added /proc/cmdline to the question. Could you please review it?

Comment: @DavidA looks ok, even after reboot if the problem persists then this is from Anonymous huge page allocation. Since the OS is not mentioned I have to assume this RHEL7 based on the kernel version number. Hence my only suggestion is disable `transparent_hugepage=never` and update the grub. Happy to have to skype debug to confirm the same.

Comment: @VipinVarghese My goal is to have a sensible hugepage configuration. If you think 20 x 1GB pages is sensible we can leave it like that.  I could try transparent_hugepage=never but maybe that would have no benefit. In summary, do you think my configuration is ok?

Comment: @DavidA if you have configured 20 pages of 1GB in grub, it should reflect as 20 1Gb in /rpoc/meminfo. Only reason for popping up 43, even after grub update and reboot is is anonymous pages is enabled and some application is using the same. If you are not concerned about 43 huge pages and not 20, IMHO then please remove those reference from the question.

Comment: @VipinVarghese I tried transparent_hugepage=never but it made no difference. I think THP is always enabled due to the tuned profile. Again, maybe it doesn't matter.  Final question (hopefully): you said you use 1GB hugepages, how many do you specify? 20?

Comment: What is the output of "cat /proc/mounts" : are there several hugetlbfs filesystems mounted ?

Comment: @DavidA I assign 24 on 2 NUMA on linux 4.15.0-135-generic

Comment: @RachidK. Thanks for your comment. I have edited my question and put the info you asked for at the end.

Comment: And what is the result of `cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled` ?

Comment: @RachidK. [always] madvise never

Comment: @DavidA if you have configured and edited grub to disable transparent huge pages, this should be `never` and not always. Something is not right. Strange to see even after reboot the OS is still not reflecting the same value. To isoalte the same, only option is different kernel ?

Comment: @RachidK. I've added an updated to my question, giving my current status, (at the end of the post). Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: @Vipin Varghese I've added an updated to my question, giving my current status, (at the end of the post). Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: @DavidA this is very interesting problem, skyp call for debug?

Comment: @VipinVarghese Thanks, I'll keep trying for a while first.

Comment: @DavidA Sure no issues. There is kernel bug on huge pages so did you try different kernel?

Comment: @VipinVarghese I am now running kernel 3.10 and Centos 7.9.2009. The behaviour is the same.

Comment: @DavidA  as per the earlier request you ahd marked `Centos 7`. I am not sure how this is a kernel > 3.10,. Hope you will try a higher kernel version

Comment: @VipinVarghese Sorry, I don't understand. I ran yum update. 'uname -r' returns 3.10.0-957.el7.x86_64

Comment: @DavidA 3.10 is kernel number while `0-957` is releases and patches. Update to a higher kernel means selecting a kernel image > 3.10. there are also a couple of things which needs to be checked, but you have mentioned you would like to try it out, will wait for you.

Comment: @VipinVarghese In /etc/sysctl.conf I found that vm.nr_hugepages = 200. This seems to have used all available memory for hugepages (i.e. 43 x 1GB). I set it to 0 and rebooted. Now 'cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge' reports zero hugepages, even though I specify 20 in boot parameters. It's not clear to me which method I should use to specify the number of hugepages.

Comment: @DavidA if you were setting from grub cmdline, then why did you need entry in `/etc/sysctl.conf`? I am also confused why both are applied on your system, did some set it deliberately?

Comment: @VipinVarghese I have set the number of hugepages to be the same (25) in grub and in /etc/sysctl.conf.  /proc/meminfo now reports 25 x 1GB pages, so it is now consistent. I will leave it like that I think. Thanks for all your help. In the EAL parameters for DPDK I set -m to 16GB. I don't know if that is excessive?

Comment: @DavidA so now lets focus on the second part of the question, can you please run your application and use `sudo numastat -p [application pid]` this will show your current memory usage. then you can start using `--scoket-limit` `--scoket-mem` to limit the pages step by step